# Find the middle of a string after first space and before last in MySql

Tags: mysql, substring

Given a Name Field with Contents "A B C D" how can I extract "B C"?

I can use:

- substring_Index(Name,' ',1) to extract 'A'
- substring_Index(Name,' ',-1) to extract 'D'

But am not sure how to combine those to get the middle string. One issue is that both 'A' and 'D' can be anywhere from 1 to 4 characters and there can also be 'A B D'. So basically looking to extract whatever is not the two substrings above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some good answers I tried my own approach which seems to automatically account for

- However many words between 'A' and 'D'
- However many letters in 'A' or 'D'
- Whether or not 'A' starts with same letter as D

Sorry for not taking time to do sqlfiddle deep in middle of project but as you can see works on any pattern:

**Original 'A B C D' pattern:**

```
 Select 'A B C D', substring('A B C D',(char_length(substring_Index('A B C D',' ',1))+2),(char_length('A B C D')-char_length(substring_Index('A B C D',' ',-1)))-(char_length(substring_Index('A B C D',' ',1))+2))
```

**More words between 'A' and 'D':**

```
Select 'A B C X D', substring('A B C X D',(char_length(substring_Index('A B C X D',' ',1))+2),(char_length('A B C X D')-char_length(substring_Index('A B C X D',' ',-1)))-(char_length(substring_Index('A B C X D',' ',1))+2))
```

**Length of 'A' and 'D' greater than one letter:**

```
Select 'AA B C DDDD', substring('AA B C DDDD',(char_length(substring_Index('AA B C DDDD',' ',1))+2),(char_length('AA B C DDDD')-char_length(substring_Index('AA B C DDDD',' ',-1)))-(char_length(substring_Index('AA B C DDDD',' ',1))+2))
```

**'A' and 'D' start with same letter (issue in earlier answer):**

```
Select 'A B C A', substring('A B C A',(char_length(substring_Index('A B C A',' ',1))+2),(char_length('A B C A')-char_length(substring_Index('A B C A',' ',-1)))-(char_length(substring_Index('A B C A',' ',1))+2))
```

Comment: A different approach is [here](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/01/23/mysql-select-the-n-th-element-from-a-delimiter-separated-value-set/):  In general, to select the N-th value from a string VALUES that contains values separated by delimiter DELIM, you have to use:`SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( VALUES, DELIM, N )`, DELIM, -1 )

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
select trim(replace(replace(col,concat(substring_Index(col,' ',1),' '),''),concat(' ',substring_Index(col,' ',-1)),'')) from foo;
```

Check sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57f88/8

Comment: @Hash Thank you it seems close though it has unexpected behavior please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9621d/1 Not sure the issue since the two terms are identical in length/structure except one ends in 'St' and one in 'Rd'. I added a couple more examples, the issue seems to be when the first letter of 'A' is the same as the first letter of 'D'?

Comment: @Hash ok I confirmed http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e95b06/1 the issue is the 'A'  and 'D' starting with the same letter but cannot figure out why. Any insights appreciated.

Comment: @Hash I voted your answer as correct, just found an error in one pattern as shown here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8257/1 not sure if you have any fixes/ideas/thoughts any are appreciated!

Comment: @user3649739, I think the problem is being caused by the fact that REPLACE() or any other function in mysql doesn't give an option for whole word only replace. Your best bet is to write a user-defined function which can split the string and return all words except first and last.